# Reverse git push that overwrote my active branch?

Tags: git

EDIT: I have the "git log -p" which seems to show all the changes in a diff mode.  Is there anyway to process this log?

Well, I inverted a push and overwrote my active branch with my master.  I can't seem to see any way to reverse this damage, either.  I've read and tried many options here, and none get back my changes.

What happened:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "...comments"
git push staging master:alerts
```

What I should have done was:

```
git push staging alerts:master
```

What I did was overwrite alerts with master on my local repository, and the damage seems to be done.  I studied and tried recommendations both in the git guides and here on SO without success.

I have tried various versions of commands such as git revert; git reset, etc.  The current hash/HEAD@{0} had none of my recent changes and the old hash/HEAD@{1} was even older.  All changes to my current branch seem to be irretrievably lost, overwritten by master.

It puzzles me that such a simple mistake could do this without warning or recourse.  I thought git protected me...  Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, so far, I am working on using the patch process.

The patch log was created by:

```
git format-patch master --stdout > my.patch
```

Move my.patch to another directory temporarily, then:

```
git checkout master
```

Move it back, then these commands should apply it:

```
git apply --stat my.patch
git apply --check my.patch
git apply --apply my.patch
```

Instead of the last command, you can signoff on the patch using:

```
git am --signoff < my.patch
```

I am checking on the success...

This all comes from: [How to create and apply a patch with git](https://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git/)

Comment: Well, I'll be.  It worked.  Now, first I back it up, then I try to commit and push it correctly this time!!!  I should mention that the comments on the post to which I referred recommended the use of the new "git cherry-pick"  command instead...

Comment: Did have to use "git push staging master --force" to make it work since staging was out of synch, but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you didn't do forced push no commits were lost. So there was nothing git should have warned you about. If you don't see you recent changes done to local alerts then you have either done something else destructive or don't look properly. You may always use 'git reflog' to recover recent local commits.

Comment: That's not what I am seeing at all.  Reflog simply shows HEAD@{0} as the most recent commit from this morning and all prior from days ago.  My local repository was overwritten en mass.  Commits were made to alerts.  When I pushed master to alerts, they were gone.

Comment: Bear in mind that reflog doesn't follow chronological order or branch structure. It is simply the log of what was happening. You need to find there you last commits before the disaster by looking at the entries of the type commit.

Comment: I've looked at the data.  The changes are gone.

Comment: I have to agree with you to a point.  The patch process would not apply to my alerts branch, only to master.  However, even with "git checkout alerts", the changes just weren't there at all.  So, your advice does carry weight, but it doesn't tell me how to get there from here.

Comment: You don't need patches when working within connected repositories. Mark the "lost" changes with temporary branches (e.g. `git branch recovery_local_alerts <SHA1>` etc.) and correct the situation with the help of reset, rebase, merge and reverts. Precise course of actions depends on a particular situation with the particular branch and whether you may/wish to overwrite remote history. You will find the answers on your question elsewhere otherwise create a more specific question. So you mark the original commits, nothing is lost and you can carefully proceed with the fix.

Comment: As I mentioned in the original question, I went through many SO answers and most of the GIT tutorial and guides with various log reviews and recovery scenarios.  Nothing mentioned in any of them recovered the missing code.  If you can explain a specific answer given the problem, tell me and I'll go back and try it.